# Replace character/characters after a specific character in a String, Java

Tags: java, string

I'm a beginner at Java and I've been working on this puzzle for a while and just can't seem to get it right.
I want a user to enter a word, any word, and for a program to go through the characters in the String one by one, and if the first character is a vowel, the next 2 characters are to be erased in the String.
After the characters have been erased, the program will go to the next character and perform the same test. If a vowel, erase the next two, if not, just print the character and move on to the next one.
For example, a random word like 'liberty' would be:
'lirty'
'banana' would be changed into  'ban'.
'caramel' becomes 'came'.

Is there a basic and simple way to acheive this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Kind Regards
///Magnus

Comment: what have you tried yet ? Do you have a sample of code ?

Comment: Check out [String class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), there is charAt(int index), replace(char oldChar, char newChar), and others method() that will be useful for your project.

Comment: I think you meant for `banana` to become `bana`, since the first `a` removed the middle 2 characters (`na`), and the last `a` is then left alone. And you can do this easily with regular expression, but that's likely not what you are looking for. Anyway, it would be `output = input.replaceAll("([aeiou])..?", "$1");`. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KduWCQ/1) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea on how to solve this:
There are 2 cases. First letter a vowel or not a vowel.
This means we need the following structure

```
if(isVowel(firstLetter)){
    //handle case with first letter a vowel
}else{
    //handle other case
}
```

Since we want to print the first letter independent of the cases we can do that before the if, so that's done.
Then in both cases you can just call the function recursively.
So for the vowel case take the substring from 3 till the end.

```
str.subString(3, str.length()-1);
```

And finally don't forget about the edge cases: what would happen if you pass in an empty string?
Or if the first is a vowel but there's only 1 letter after?
This results in the following implementation:

```
public void printSpecial(String str){
    if(str==null || str.isEmpty()){
        return; //No letters to print
    }
    char firstLetter = str.charAt(0);
    System.out.print(firstLetter); //print the current letter

    if(isVowel(firstLetter)){
        if(str.length()<4){
            return; //Not enough letters to continue
        }
        printSpecial(str.substring(3, str.length()-1));
    } else {
        if(str.length()==1){
            return; //Last letter done
        }
        printSpecial(str.substring(1, str.length()-1));
    }
}
```

So the only thing left to do is implement the method

```
public boolean isVowel(char letter){

}
```

But I'll leave this up to you :)

Comment: Quick note: I didn't check if this code actually works, or if the indices are all correct. My idea was to just give the general way of solving a problem like this.  In retrospect I think it's actually against the terms of this site to not let you try to write the code yourself.  Then again, I feel that it's exactly these kind of answers that could help people figure out how to solve these kind of problems in general, so it might help in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "caramel";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(str);
    System.out.println("Before deletion=" + sb);
    for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        if (sb.charAt(i) == 'a' || sb.charAt(i) == 'e' || sb.charAt(i) == 'i' || sb.charAt(i) == 'o' || sb.charAt(i) == 'u') {
            if(i==sb.length()-2)
            {//prevent index out of bounds
                sb.deleteCharAt(i+1);
            }
            else if(i==sb.length()-1)
            {
             //prevent index out of bounds   
            }
            else
            { //delete 2 charaters 
                sb.deleteCharAt(i+1);
                sb.deleteCharAt(i+1);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("After deletion=" + sb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I'll give them a go..! :-)